# Why no segfault error when referring an object after free?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting `segmentation fault` in my application, and while testing with sample applications I found that object reference after freeing it not resulting segmentation fault. Below is the test code which I run,

```
hash_node  *node_obj=new hash_node();
delete node_obj;
node_obj->var1=0;
return 0;
```

I just overloaded `new` to use `malloc` and `delete` to use `free`.
Can any one please advise me in this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accessing a location in memory using a pointer that has been deleted/freed is undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour doesn't imply that a segfault will occur.

Answer (score 0):

It is an undefined behavior, so you cannot expect a segmentation fault here. You can refer Stroustrup's "Design and Evolution of C++" which says:

> It is not possible to change what a reference refers to after
>   initialization. That is, once a C++ reference is initialized it cannot
>   be made to refer to a different object later; it cannot be re-bound. I
>   had in the past been bitten by Algol68 references where r1=r2 can
>   either assign through r1 to the object referred to or assign a new
>   reference value to r1 (re-binding r1) depending on the type of r2. I
>   wanted to avoid such problems in C++.

Answer (score 0):

> Segmentation fault happens when a process tries to access memory location which its not suppose to. Memory outside the area which is allotted to the process.
>
> ---
>
> In your code, accessing memory already freed is Undefined Behaviour.